# Не выбирает базу данных

Tags: php, pdo, mariadb

Момент создания базы

```
<?php

include 'db.php';


$stmt = $pdo->prepare("
    CREATE DATABASE playground
");

$stmt ->execute();
```

Момент выбора базы

```
<?php

include 'db.php';


$stmt = $pdo->prepare("
    USE playground
");

$stmt ->execute();
```

Ошибка:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.
>   Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code
>   is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query
>   buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

не нужно использовать `prepare(...)` при таком запросе

используй `$pdo->exec("CREATE DATABASE playground");`

Comment: Да ваш ответ помог. А где можно было прочитать про это $pdo->exec("CREATE DATABASE playground");. Везде пишут что сначала должен быть prepare(...) Только потом execute

Comment: `prepare` нужен если ты запрос будешь выполнять много раз и требуется передавать значения переменных в базу (INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT запросы)